# Can you use the asp.net membership provider in a windows application?

Tags: .net, asp.net, wpf, asp.net-membership

The Asp.Net membership provider has some clear uses in a web app.  I am thinking about trying to leverage some of the features in a windows application (more specifically WPF).  Does anyone know if it is possible to use the core features in a windows app?  I am mostly just looking for it to create my database tables, and maintain users, roles, and profiles.  I obviously do not need to use the built-in web controls (e.g. Login).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a winform app that talks to DotNetNuke (DNN). DNN uses the Asp.net membership provider, so the source will work for other apps that use that membership provider as well. It's a very simple app, so you should be able to read the source easily.

http://www.datakido.com/downloads/Token/ViewInfo/ItemId/3

You should be able to adapt the source to work with WPF.

Comment: Your simple app is 404.

Comment: The old site went down. Put the download on another site.

Answer (score 10):

Yes.  Membership, roles and profiles are all features of Visual Studio 2008 Client Application Services (Services tab of a project properties)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384297.aspx

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/DanielMoth/Client-Application-Services-with-Visual-Studio-2008/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

All the configuration can be done within app.config instead web.config of asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are creating a 3.5 application (WPF 4 won't work yet) - Then you must import the reference System.Web. This will allow you to use "using System.Web.Security;" like you normally would in a web app... now you can access stuff such as Membership.CreateUser()

Your app.config file has to be configured for your provider along with a connection string.