# ASP.NET membership providers in non-web apps?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership, ldap, membership-provider

Does anyone know if it's possible to use an ASP.NET membership (and role) provider in a non-web app (ie in a desktop C# app)?

Related question -- is there an LDAP membership provider (it looks like SharePoint has one, but I don't think it's the same as the ASP.NET provider).  I'm sure the Active Directory one is probably close, but I'm not sure if it would work against Novell or Sun's LDAP servers.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444230/can-you-use-the-asp-net-membership-provider-in-a-windows-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've wondered the same thing and after a bit of research found out about [Client Application Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384339.aspx) in VS 2008.

I understand using CAS you can use the ASP.NET Membership and Role Providers, though I haven't tried this yet.

Here are some references that look useful:

[Implementing Application Security with Client Application Services in VS2008](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/ClientApplicationServices.aspx)
[Client Application Services Walkthrough](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ClientApplicationServices.aspx)