# Examples of simple user sessions in WPF Desktop

Tags: wpf, session, authentication, desktop

Are there any decent examples of (or tutorials on) simple user sessions in a WPF desktop app?

My app contains an Entity Framework library, a couple in-house class libraries, and a presentation layer that's a WPF project. We're not presently hooking into any webservices or building a WCF layer.

Still, people will log into the app using a Citrix account- with many people possibly using the same account (client's design there), so I'd like to create a user session for each login. How tractable is this on the desktop? I've found an [Auto logoff example for WPF Desktop](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AutologoffWPF.aspx?msg=3238811) on codeproject, but no basic implementations of the logon/session. All the WPF session info I've found so far has been browser based, mostly hitting WCF services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on searching due to @Matt_West's response, I was guided to the fact that I shouldn't be searching for "user session management" in WPF, but for "Membership Services." Once I did that, I found a [SO Thread on Membership Services in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444230/can-you-use-the-asp-net-membership-provider-in-a-windows-application)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by user session? I would assume by what you are describing that you want your users to log in to your app (separately from their Windows login). If this is what you mean than you will basically be rolling your own user and session management system using your database. I would model it off of what others have already done but you could simplify it to meet your exact needs. Here is an example of a WPF interface into the ASP.NET membership system. You would probably want to create something similar (although if you don't need roles and such it will make it much simpler).

http://wpfmembershipadmin.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks, that gives me something to work with. I wonder if there's a simpler way to do it assuming you use the Windows login. Not sure if that'll work with their Citrix system, but it'd be nice to see other options.