# How to implement user sessions in wpf?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, wpftoolkit

How to implement user sessions in wpf?

I have a XBAP application in which I am required to implement the user sessions
IS there any way I can achieve this in WPF?

Thank you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF doesn't implement the concept of sessions.

You may use a session provider or maybe an asp web service to produce a custom solution.

Or you could use an [Isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy.aspx) for all the users data.

Also check out some previous posts which address this:

- [Examples of simple user sessions in WPF Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993834/examples-of-simple-user-sessions-in-wpf-desktop)
- [Can you use the asp.net membership provider in a windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444230/can-you-use-the-asp-net-membership-provider-in-a-windows-application)

Comment: I had most luck with Isolated storage. You can use this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-read-and-write-to-files-in-isolated-storage