# Adding a Single Web Service to an Existing ASP.NET Application

Tags: asp.net, winforms, web-services, webforms, asmx

I've written an ASP.NET website along with a companion WinForms desktop application, which is used to maintain the site.

The desktop application needs to create a user. However, this is awkward because I would need to ensure all the membership settings are exactly the same as they are in my website's web.config file.

It would be easier if my desktop application could "call into" the website somehow and tell it to create a user. It seems like a web service would be a good option for this. However, Visual Studio doesn't have an option to add an ASMX file. And if I create a separate, web service application, then that application would have the same problem my desktop application has.

Is there a way to add a single web service to an existing ASP.NET application? Any links? Thanks.

Comment: Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444230/can-you-use-the-asp-net-membership-provider-in-a-windows-application

Comment: Thanks, but that article is about using the membership classes from a desktop application, which I'm already doing.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? Express? Professional? 2003? 2010?

Comment: See my updated answer below. Add New Item, then scroll down to Web Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Visual Studio doesn't have an option to add an ASMX file

In the Web application project, or the WinForms project? I assume you mean that you cannot add a *Web Reference* from within your WinForms project; adding an *.asmx* file to the *WinForms* project is not necessary. The Web application project should have the .asmx file, which is *called by the WinForms project* using a *web reference*.

In the WinForms project you can consume a web service by right-clicking *References* in the Solution Explorer, then choosing **Add Service Reference...** (in Visual Studio 2008; other versions may say *Add Web Reference...*). Then just enter the web address (which may be local in your case, e.g. `localhost/foo.asmx`) of the web service (.asmx).

See the section "To call an XML Web service synchronously" in this MSDN article: [Calling XML Web Services from Windows Forms](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818364).

As an alternative, [this MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818364) shows how to use the WSDL tool to generate a class that can consume a `*.asmx` URL. (The article uses VB, but you can switch the parameter to CS to generate C#.)

**Update**

To add an `.asmx` file to your Web project, right-click the project in Visual Studio, select **Add -> New Item... -> Web Service**. If there is not a "Web Service" item any where in the template browser dialog that comes up, then you are missing the template or you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I meant I saw no option to add an ASMX file to an existing ASP.NET project. (See title.)

Comment: Then either you're missing the Web Service template or there's something wrong with your project file. This is a very basic function of Visual Studio. Create a new Web application project and see if you can create a Web Service (.asmx) in that; if not, something's wrong.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. **Add New Item** adds an item to your existing Web project, it does *not* create a new project. Right-click the *project* (not the *solution*) and select Add -> New Item...

Comment: Ack! Now I do see it. I swear I ran up and down the list of items to add several times and did not see it. Not sure what happened there.