# What's similar to the Membership Provider in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you use the asp.net membership provider in a windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444230/can-you-use-the-asp-net-membership-provider-in-a-windows-application)

I'm a junior ASP.NET developer and I might need to build a WinFrom based application but I'm not sure how security works in WinForms !? So do we still, like use the Membership, Roles and stuff ? or there are new frameworks that help us to complete this job ?

It's a simple application and I big company might buy it, So I just want make sure to deliver something secured and bug-free as much as I can. so how do I start ?

Comment: Indeed, take the second answer (not the accepted answer) to the marked duplicate. I especially approve of your preference to not reinvent the wheel where security is concerned!

Comment: Thanks guys. And thanks for the support Jeremy. And btw do you have like any good books on developing WinForms that can cover all the topics I might need to know the basics for developing a WinForm application and hopefully it covers the security part ?