# How to do authentication and authorization in c# windows application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing an windows application where I want to add user based role to the form. But I am bit confused how to do in windows application?

Comment: Do you havea database that contain users?  If you don't then what you want is not possible because frankly, it makes sense to authenticate a user, on a local machine unless your talking about using microsoft's active domain service.

Comment: i have an user table and role table where i will save user details and roles respectively. roles are like add,edit,view,delete

Comment: In order to answer your question, we need to know how you want to authenticate your users.  Would you like to check their username/password against a database?  Would you like to use their Windows Identity?  Would you like to use x509 Certificates?

Comment: As @Ramhound implied, we'd need to know a lot more to answer this question in any sort of useful fashion.  1) Where are you storing (or planning to store) your user information? 2) Where are you storing (or planning to store) your list of roles? 3) Where are you storing (or planning to store) your user/role mappings? 4) What are you securing?  Certain actions within the application, or the ability to run the application itself? 5) Is the application in-house or shrinkwrap software or something else?  These are just off the top of my head.

Comment: Also if this homework of some sort - tag as "homework", it will allow you to get better answers (i.e. using smartcard for authentication for homweork is likley overkill :))

Answer (score 4):

You might want to consider using the [SqlMemebershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx).  [You can use the ASP.NET Membership provider mechanism in Windows Forms Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444230/can-you-use-the-asp-net-membership-provider-in-a-windows-application).

See [this article](http://www.theproblemsolver.nl/usingthemembershipproviderinwinforms.htm) for a walk-thorugh.

Comment: It seems a little silly to use the SqlMembershipProvider for a desktop application.  Unless of course we are dealing with a remote database.